# How detailed can I be for embroidery/patch personalization?

Tags: logo, illustration, embroidery

I was tasked with designing a logo for the EMEA team and from our meeting they want to have the EMEA (Europe, Middle East, Africa) in their logo. I started tracing out the countries, but am afraid when the get their merch personalized, that the company will say the design is too intricate. Is this kind of design too 'ornate/detailed' for that kind of personalization?

Are there any tricks to showing countries in embroidery? Will I need to simplify this?

[image: EMEA]

Comment: Do you know how big it will be embroidered and the thread count of the embroidery? Without that information theres not much you can do.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I'm not really sure if it will be embroidered onto the jacket itself, or if they will make a small patch. If I had to guess a size, maybe 5" wide, 2" tall?

Comment: One question you should ask is, "what's the purpose of this?" Regardless of whether or not they *can* use this, you need to consider *should* you use something like this anyway

Comment: @ZachSaucier I suggested to use something more relevant to Services, such as tools, a wrench, gears, etc. But we already have a services team similar to this. The difference is that this is the EMEA service team and they would like to reflect the EMEA in their logo.

Comment: Why is half of Finland missing? And why is of Russia in the map, either its in or out? To me your right border seems a bit off.

Comment: @joojaa because they aren't in our specific territory for our EMEA team

Comment: So your emea team only covers half of Finland and arbitrary parts of Russia? italians might also have some problem with the map.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've cut me off that map too... or at least squashed me in to England a bit

Comment: Hey guys, no hard feelings, as a designer and not geography wiz, [this was the map](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/fedora-web.git/plain/fedoracommunity.org/static/images/worldmap-emea.png) I was given to trace. I mentioned your comments and was told this map is fine.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯